# Don't bring nothing vs Don't bring anything

Tags: word-choice

My friend came to visit me and asked  If I wanted something. I wanted to tell him to not bring anything. In this context what is the the right sentence to tell him among two of the following:

a) Don't bring **nothing**!

b) Don't bring **anything**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bring anything is the right choice. 
Don't bring nothing is a double negative sentence which actually translates to a positive.

Comment: The incorrect use of "Don't bring nothing" is a relatively common, as is "I didn't do nothing" where the intended meaning "I am innocent"

Comment: Note that if you're going to a birthday party and didn't intend to purchase the birthday boy/girl a gift, your friend saying "don't bring nothing" probably isn't a double negative. :P

Comment: @JavaLatte that is actually Americanism.

Comment: @John Clifford: it is a double negative, but it's an **intentional** double negative.

Comment: @JavaLatte Psh, stop nitpicking my clever joke. :P

Comment: @MAKZ: Double negatives have been a part of the English language since long before America had its current name: Chaucer (1342-1400) used them.

Comment: It is a common myth that "'Don't bring nothing' actually translates to a positive". It can mean that, with suitable context and (usually) special emphasis. But overwhelmingly, when English speakers say "Don't bring nothing" they both mean _and are understood to mean_ "Don't bring anything". Therefore, since meaning lies _only_ in what is meant and understood by an utterance, that is what the sentence predominantly means.